# Django. How do I add a field to a query?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-queryset

I have a Room model and I want to add the `is_member` boolean field to a queryset with rooms. How can i do this? I was thinking of using `.annotate ()`, but that doesn't work for my task.

**models.py**

```
class Room(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
```

**I present the solution like this:**

```
rooms = Room.objects.all()
user = request.user
for room in rooms:
    members = room.members.all()
    is_member = user in members
    room.is_member = is_member # <- edited line
```

Help me please

**Update!**
**Sorry.** I wrote `user.is_member = is_member` instead of `room.is_member = is_member`

Comment: what are you expected to get with your queryset first

Comment: i want to serialize rooms with "is_member" = True or False

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Create a model called Profile and add the is_member field to it.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_profile')
    is_member = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

And use `Profile` for member field as `ForeignKey` instead of `User`.

```
class Room(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    member = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True)
```

And then set the `is_member` field of the `Profile` object to True or False accordingly. see below code:

```
user = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
user.is_member = Room.objects.filter(member=user).exists()
```

Comment: Sorry. I wrote "user.is_member = is_member" instead of "room.is_member = is_member". I already updated this line in my ask.